# How to use StreamReader in C# (newbie)

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I'm trying to read the contents of a text file, in this case a list of computer names (Computer1, computer2 etc,) and I thought that StreamReader would be what you would use but when I do the following:

```
StreamReader arrComputer = new StreamReader(FileDialog.filename)();
```

I got this exception:

```
The type or namespace name 'StreamReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm very new to C# so I'm sure I'm making a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to import the `System.IO` namespace. Put this at the top of your .cs file:

```
using System.IO;
```

Either that, or explicitly qualify the type name:

```
System.IO.StreamReader arrComputer = new System.IO.StreamReader(FileDialog.filename);
```

Comment: Wow! That helps! Can't believe I missed that.  Man, this place rocks! thanks to everyone who pointed this out to me. Perfect!

Answer (score 9):

You'll need:

```
using System.IO;
```

At the top of the .cs file.
If you're reading text content I recommend you use a TextReader which is bizarrely a base class of StreamReader.

try:

```
using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(/* your args */))
{
}
```

The using block just makes sure it's disposed of properly.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
using System.IO;


StreamReader arrComputer = new StreamReader(FileDialog.filename);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.  I saw your reply earlier and totally missed the using System.IO; namespace...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the System assembly in your reference of the project and add this to the using part:

```
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you include `using System.IO` in the usings declaration

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are have "using System.IO;" at the top of your module. Also, you don't need the extra parenthesis at the end of "new StreamReader(FileDialog.filename)".

Answer (score 2):

StreamReader is defined in System.IO.  You either need to add

`using System.IO;`

to the file or change your code to:

```
System.IO.StreamReader arrComputer = new System.IO.StreamReader(FileDialog.filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the System.IO assembly.  You can do this via the "My Project" properties page under the References tab.

Comment: My Project only exists in Visual Basic.NET projects.